# How do i calculate combination of a group of numbers where sum of each group is equal to a number?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Let's say I have 3 number `[1,2,3]` how can I find the number of combinations of these numbers that will satisfy  4 for example.

so in the case of 4, the lists can be as follows:

```
1 1 1 1 
2 2 
2 1 1
3 1
```

so for this case, i'll have 4 possible combinations that satisfy my equation

Comment: Almost sounds like this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: almost but my numbers doesnt neceserily have to follow each other on prper orther

Comment: Do you just want the number of restricted partitions or do you want to list them all?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to list them, you can use recursion.  Sort your list of numbers (if necessary) and start from the largest one, which we call $k$.  The ways to sum to $n$ are $k$ plus the ways to sum to $n-k$ and the ways to sum to $n$ without using $k$.  Each of those branches decreases the complexity of the problem, one by reducing the number to sum to and one by decreasing the list of possible summands.

If you just want to count them, the same approach works.  The function should just return a count of solutions instead of a list of them.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the equation $x+y=5$. We have 6 solutions, $(0,5),(1,4),(2,3),(3,2),(4,1),(5,0)$. Represent them in binary, albeit an unusual one.

> $\begin{align}(0,5)&=(011111)\\(1,4)&=(101111)\\(2,3)&=(110111)\\(3,2)&=(111011)\\(4,1)&=(111101)\\(5,0)&=(111110)\end{align}$

Take $a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n=m$. We see that $\text{max}(n)=m$. So, we take $w+x+y+z=4$ in binary. Here we have four $1$s, since the numbers add to $4$, and three $0$s to seperate the $1$s. Thus, the number of ordered pairs $(w,x,y,z)$ such that $w+x+y+z=4$, given that a variable may be zero is ${{7!}\over{3!4!}}=35$.

But that is wrong, since either of the variables may be $4$, which we are not allowed. So, since there are 4 variables, we do $35-4=31$.

But even that is wrong. For every $w$, we can have any of $x,y,z$ to be $(4-w)$, and the other two $0$. But since we have three other variables so any one can be considered that. So we have $31-(3-1)×4×3=7$. We have $(3-1)$ because this method counts them three while we count them one. We have $4$ variables to act as $w$. We have $3$ since each variable has $3$ values possible.

Since $(1,1,2)=(1,2,1)=(2,1,1)$, we see that there are some special repetitions we have left out. There are three such, and thus we have $7-3=4$.